# How can I limit the number of RemoteApp sessions to 1 per user?

Tags: windows-7, remoteapp

We have an application where only one instance of the program can be run at a time. Otherwise terrible data corruption happens. Our users currently run this program as a RemoteApp from a Windows 7 "server". However I want to be able to limit the number of instances of it to be limited to 1, so that a user can't accidentally run two instances of the program. Is this possible? And if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this as far as I know.  But you could hypothetically write a little stub application or script that checks to see if the process is running in the context of that user already and exits if it is.  If not, it launches the app as normal.  You'd then point your RemoteApp shortcut to this stub instead of directly to the application.

Comment: I actually also realized that by default Windows will only a user to have a RemoteApp open from one computer. So switching computers actually takes over the previous RemoteApp's session which is exactly what I'd wanted. Doesn't work if running 2 RemoteApp sessions on the same machine though.